# why is content in UICollectionViewCell located incorrectly?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I have next code in controller, which set frame of `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3.8, height: self.view.frame.size.width / 3.8)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        devicesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Chunk of code in delegate method, which call cell's method, which set data in it:

```
if let deviceCell = cell as? DevicesCollectionViewCell , let devices = room?.devices, let roomName = room?.roomName {
                deviceCell.setDeviceInfoInCell(device: devices[indexPath.item], roomName: roomName, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3.8)
            }
```

chunk of code in cell's class:

```
        self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: width, height: width)
        self.stateImageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x + width - (width / 3), y: self.frame.origin.y, width: width / 3, height: width / 3)
        self.lightImageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x + 10, y: self.frame.origin.y + 10, width: width / 3, height: width / 3)
        self.sensImageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x + 10, y: self.frame.origin.y + 10, width: width / 5, height: width / 5)
        self.humdityImageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x + 10, y: self.frame.origin.y + sensImageView.frame.size.height + 15, width: width / 5, height: width / 5)
```

But when my CollectionView is showed, imageviews inside placed incorrectly, sometimes I didn't see them. Why they gets incorrect coordinates?
Screenshots: only one picture in one cell
[image: Screenshot1]

and here icons goes anywhere:

[image: Screenshot2]

**Updating**
according the comments I'm trying to use layoutIfNeeds and adding this method to my cell's class:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.stateImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.sensImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.humdityImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.lightImageView.layoutSubviews()
    }
```

But it is don't solved my problem, and now labels goes anywhere too. Please help me. New screenShot:
[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: Show Screenshot of what content is located incorrectly.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh, I edited code, added screenshots

Comment: Consider using AutoLayout instead of setting up frames for every single subview in a cell.

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov, I'm do lazy initialization of this subwiews inside cell's class. Initializes they with frames, and in method use autoLayout?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should put your layout code for the cell content in the cell's `layoutSubviews()` function.

Comment: @LGP, it doesn't help me

Comment: I think you should put your “chunk of code in cell’s class” in your layoutSubviews().

Comment: @LGP, it's not help too.